# Magento memory leak

Tags: php, magento, memory, hosting, overflow

I’m experiencing some problems on my magento 1.6.1.0 site, that looks like a memory leak. Server went a few times totally down, as I am on a shared server my hosting company isn’t exactly glad with me and threatens to ban my site from their server because they say it’s a threat to the total server.

When server was down in the server log we can read first:
NY-SH-02 suhosin[31654]: ALERT - canary mismatch on efree() - heap overflow detected at 0x7f7567b90e58 (attacker 'REMOTE_ADDR not set', file '/var/www/sites/mysite.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php', line 119)
About 78lines with the exact message on the same time

1 time in between system writes 
NY-SH-02 suhosin[30574]: ALERT - canary mismatch on efree() - heap overflow detected at 0x7f7567b90e58 (attacker 'REMOTE_ADDR not set', file '/var/www/sites/mysite.com/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php', line 586)

Half a minute after this the following messages come
NY-SH-02 suhosin[32532]: ALERT - script tried to increase memory_limit to 536870912 bytes which is above the allowed value (attacker ‘ip-adress', file '/var/www/sites/mysite.com/index.php', line 2)

This line appears like 50times but with different php files but always speak of line 2

The ip adresses in the last alertline defined as attacker are sometimes different, 2 times was a google bot, 2 times was a different ip.

Does anyone experienced this problem before or knows where I have to start looking because this is a needle in a hay stack.

Comment: Magento doesn't work on shared hosting. It's very resource expensive.

Comment: "shared server my hosting company isn’t exactly glad with me and threatens to ban my site from their server because they say it’s a threat to the total server." There's your problem.

Comment: Shared hosting requires applications to play well with others, Magento often refuses to share resources and does not play well with others. You choose a hosting plan that will run Magento and that will allow for the caching, script memory space and database tuning to allow for performance. Most "memory leaks" in Magento are found to be inadequate resources allocation that causes requests to the PHP interpreter and database to stack up.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't so much a memory leak as it is Magento has significant memory requirements. I'm not a security expert, but I know `suhosin` is a PHP extension that's aimed at tightening up PHP's security.  It appears to be complaining that

1. PHP's memory limit is being exhausted, which it interprets as an attack.
2. That a PHP file is using `ini_set` to raise the memory limit to 536870912 bytes, which is 512MB exactly.

Your shared host doesn't have enough memory allocated to each shared host instances for Magento to run.  If a user hits a page that has a significant number of non-cached items, it's feasible for Magento to momentarily use 200 MB, 300 MB, even 400 MB of memory.  During checkout Magento deliberately rebuilds caches related to the order to make sure it's getting the most up-to-date item — the quick fix for this it to up the memory limit, which is probably what's happening #2

You need a host that advertises Magento support.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses, i'm gonna look for a dedicated server for my website. only are afraid of all settings that i now have to do my self. but thats the way to learn things. Again thx

Comment: @user1588408 You don't need a dedicated sever, just a Magento specialized host  .